# Mysql C API: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: mysql, c

I use the C api  mysql, however, I encounter an error when I am connected to the database, and I chose the selected item.
"Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

```
boolean
check_token(char *token) {
    MYSQL_RES   *res;
    MYSQL_ROW   row;
    char        *pass;
    char        query[200];

    snprintf(query, 200, "SELECT * FROM tokens WHERE token = \"%s\"", token); //  SELECT * FROM tokens WHERE token = "84ds4d3d3sd453s"
    if (mysql_query(&db, query)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(&db));
        return (FALSE);
    }
    printf("OK\n");
    if (!(res = mysql_store_result(&db))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(&db));
        return (FALSE);
    }
    if (!(row = mysql_fetch_row(res)))
        return (FALSE);
    pass = row[1];
    printf("Le token est %s\n", pass);
    mysql_free_result(res);
    return (TRUE);
}
```

No further requests are made just before. Just the connection to the database that is successful.

Comment: Where exactly doe this occur? On `if (mysql_query(&db, query)) {`?  It sounds like you've still got another query executing that you haven't freed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that you will not free the `MYSQL_RES` if `mysql_fetch_row` call fails, making next subsequent calls fail.

`free` the result before returning from the function.

```
if (!(row = mysql_fetch_row(res)))
{
    mysql_free_result(res); //Free before returning
    return (FALSE);
}

pass = row[1];
printf("Le token est %s\n", pass);
mysql_free_result(res);
return (TRUE);
```

Comment: The error appears at `if (mysql_query(&db, query)) {`

Comment: Yes, but i don t have request before